# How we get and store the editText value in card RecylerView in Android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Please Give me an Solution I am new in Android, On BindView Holder Code is:

I am using Cards in RecylerView

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SeedlingViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.seedling_CardView.setTag(position);

        if(holder instanceof SeedlingViewHolder) {
            holder.centerUnit.setText("Assigned To : "+placedOrderDetailBeanArray.get(position).eoCenterUnit);
            holder.creationDate.setText("Creation Date :"+placedOrderDetailBeanArray.get(position).orderCreationDate);
            holder.no_bag.setText("No. of Bag :"+placedOrderDetailBeanArray.get(position).noOfBags);
            holder.no_seedling.setText("No. of Seedling :"+placedOrderDetailBeanArray.get(position).noOfSeedling);

          /*  holder.target.setTag(position);
             value=(String) holder.centerUnit.getTag(R.id.seedling_Target_GM);*/

            holder.save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    placedOrderDetailBeanArray.get(position).target = targetVal;
                    Log.v("ORDER DEATIL ***** ",placedOrderDetailBeanArray.toString());
                }
            });
            Log.v("Seeding Adapter","Holder");
        }


    }
```

My edit Text name is Target an I want to save this value in a Variable so that I can send it on server Later

```
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return placedOrderDetailBeanArray.size();
    }

    public class SeedlingViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public TextView creationDate,completionDate,no_seedling,no_bag,achievement,centerUnit;
        public EditText target;
        public Button save;
        public View seedling_CardView;
        public SeedlingViewHolder(View convertView) {
            super(convertView);
            seedling_CardView = (CardView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cardViewSeedling_GM);
            seedling_CardView.setOnClickListener(this);

            creationDate=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.seedling_CreationDate_GM);
            no_seedling=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.seedling_no_seedling_GM);
            no_bag=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.seedling_bag_GM);
            centerUnit=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.seedlingCenterUnit_GM);
            save=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnSave_GM);

            target=(EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.seedling_Target_GM);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: So you just want to get the value from EditText?

Comment: Yes I want to getedit Text value and want to save in a variable

Comment: You can save the value in `SharedPreferences` then get the value when is needed.

Comment: Not need to save i shared preferences @tahsinRupam , You can save your edit text value in array list by using model mechanizm

Comment: Yeah, that's another solution indeed.

Comment: @AbhinavSrivastava can you show me you model code.

Comment: He could always assign a different key for each row. It's just a solution may not be most efficient. Creating model, setting and getting the values might be a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

First: Create custom wrapper class with setter and getter methods with needed variables

Like This:

```
public class WrapperClass {

    private String Name;
    private String MaidID;
    private String Phone;

    public WrapperClass(String name,String Phone,String Mail) {
        Name = name;
        this.Phone=Phone;
        MaidID=Mail;

    }


    public String getMaidID() {
        return MaidID;
    }

    public void setMaidID(String maidID) {
        MaidID = maidID;
    }

// Other Variable Getter Setter with constructor of values you want to retrieve
```

Second:
Create Custom List on Main activity where you have you edit text

```
List<WrapperClass> Data=new ArrayList<WrapperClass>();
```

Then call constructor like this

```
WrapperClass wrap=new WrapperClass(nameEdittext.gettext().toString,MailEdittext.gettext().toString,PhoneEdittext.gettext().toString);
```

Then Add WrapperClass Object into list

```
data.add(wrap)
```

Finally in onBindView Holder get value like this

```
    wrapperClass = UsersList.get(position);
holder.Name.setText(wrapperClass.getName());
```

Note:Don't forget to pass custom list as parameter of recyclerAdapter.